# SelectedIndex of a DataGridViewComboBoxCell? VB.NET

Tags: windows, vb.net, datagrid, combobox

How do I set SelectedIndex of a DataGridViewComboBoxCell?

**The code fill the combobox with items, but I need to select one of them**

My Code:

```
 Dim cListItems As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Combobox_values)

                If ds.Tables("items_prices").Rows(0).Item("item_selldozen") > 0 Then
                    Dim item_selldozen As String = ds.Tables("items_prices").Rows(0).Item("item_selldozen")
                    cListItems.Add(New Combobox_values("Docena (" + item_selldozen + ")", item_selldozen))
                End If


                Dim dgvcbc As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = DirectCast(CType(main.ActiveMdiChild, discount_new_discount).discountitems_new_discount.Rows(last_row).Cells(3), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)

                dgvcbc.DataSource = cListItems 'Fill Remote Comboboxcell
                dgvcbc.DisplayMember = "Text"
                dgvcbc.ValueMember = "Value"
```

Comment: When do you want to set the selected index?

Comment: yes i want to set any selected index

Comment: I meant during what event or action you want to set it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a ComboBoxColumn in your DataGridView and you want to know what is the selected index of the combo box, then you need to do this:

> 1. Handle the EditingControlShowing event of DataGridView. In this event handler, check if the current column is of our interest. Then we
>      create a temporary ComboBox object and get the selected index:

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs)
    If dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        ' Check box column
        Dim comboBox As ComboBox = TryCast(e.Control, ComboBox)
        comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += New EventHandler(AddressOf comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged)
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim selectedIndex As Integer = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox).SelectedIndex
    MessageBox.Show("Selected Index = " & selectedIndex)
End Sub
```